# Push Items to an Array using index values contained in a set

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

Let's say I have some empty arrays `array1 = [], array2 = [], array3 = []`

And some data that is contained in double indexed arrays like so `this.data[row][cell]`

And I have a set `newSet()` of integers that can have variable sized depending on the data and what information is found within each `cell` in the row. Is there a way to iterate over the set so that `array1` contains all the values from `this.data[row][(SetValue1)]`,`array2` would contain all the values from `this.data[row][(SetValue2)]` etc.? I'm thinking a for-loop iterating over the values of the set to start with but am not sure what might be an elegant solution to this question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by `SetValue1`, `SetValue2`, etc.?

Comment: I am talking about each of the values or keys in the Set

Comment: @Barmar so if the set contains the values `{4,5,6}` push `this.data[row][4]` into `array1`, `this.data[row][5]` into `array2`, and `this.data[row][6]` into `array3`

Comment: What if the set contains more than 3 values? Do they wrap around?

Comment: thankfully the data that I am working with won't yield a set with more than three values but theoretically no any added values to the set would require its own array

Answer (score 0):

Put your arrays in another array so you can use the index into the set to reference the corresponding array.

```
arrays = [array1, array2, array3];
var index = 0;
newSet().forEach((val) => arrays[index++].push(this.data[row][val]));
```

Comment: Are you sure there are only 3 elements in the set?

Comment: Can be anywhere from 1-3

Comment: Sets are weird. When you iterate them with `forEach`, the index is the same as the value. I've changed the code to use a separate index variable.

Comment: What will make it more clear? Does the updated answer work?

Answer (score -1):

(this answer is in c sharp but look at it and check if you can take the idea to javaScript )if you meant to create a jagged array from the 2-dimensional array this is my solution:

```
            public static int[][] MoveToJaggedArray(int[,] a)//defining a function
            {
                int row = a.GetLength(0);//number of rows
                int Length = a.GetLength(1);//Length \ width of the array

                int[][] na = new int[row][];//setting an array of array


                for(int i =0;i<row;i++)//running on each row
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)//run on each cell
                        na[i][k] = a[i, k];//transferring value in array a in location row =i widthPlace =k to to array in location i in array na and within the array widthPlace = k 
                }
               return na;
            }
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript? Looks like Java to me and I think the original question was in reference to JS.

Comment: this is c sharp but I decided to answer because I thought he could take the Idea and transfer it to javascript

Comment: yeah not gonna lie this doesn't make a lot of sense to me

Comment: I add some comments So Take a look again